# how to restore top level menu on panel in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, compiz, menu, panel, macbuntu

I tried to install "Macbuntu" which is not compatible with 13.04 and I don't know why? But I used force option on command line nothing changed so I uninstalled "macbuntu". Now the problem is that the top menu just disappeared. For example when I'm using sublime_text or Chrome there is no menu option (File, Edit, etc..) on the panel. I tried using `unity --reset-icons` option but it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.4 does not exist. I think you meant 13.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Type in the following command then hit Enter.

   sudo `apt-get install synaptic`
3. Go to the terminal and type `gksu synaptic`. You will be prompted
   for your password. Type Unity in the quick filter bar.
4. Right click on the Unity package (in the list in the middle of the
   window), and choose Mark for Reinstallation.
5. Click the apply button, and wait for the changes to finish.
6. Close Synaptic, and the terminal. You may need to log out and back
   in to see the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling Macbuntu will remove appmenu-gtk so you have to install it again: `sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt indicator-appmenu`