# No application menu in the Panel

Tags: unity, panel, appmenu, macbuntu

I've tried Macbuntu, but did not quite like it, so I uninstalled it but Ubuntu didn't restore completely.

There are now only close, minimize, maximize buttons in Panel, while originally there should be other application menu options like "file, edit, view, help etc...", which disappeared now.

It looks like this:

[image]

I've tried reset Unity by

```
unity --reset
```

but it does not work.

I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.

Comment: The compiz-settings app can restore your window decorations, as can gconf editor and such like.  It's under desktop effects.  I hear 14.04 will reimplement the menu's to the application window, but until then you can tweak your distro or use something else like gnome-flashback.

Comment: @bleeves thanks for answering. By compiz-settings, do you mean uncheck and check effects>>window decoration? I've also tried this, but didn't work for me. By gnome-flashback, can you please explain to me in more details?

Comment: Yes I did mean window decoration as you have described.  I'm sorry if that did not work for you in unity.  You can try reinstalling ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: @bleeves any method that I can reinstall ubuntu withouting affecting my personal settings? or simply just reinstall unity?

Comment: Please use the answer system. This isn't a forum. Remove your edited content, use "reply" instead, reply your own question, then accept your own answer. It will help other with the same issue, and also improve the visibility of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved after reading another post:

[how to restore top level menu on panel in ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349810/how-to-restore-top-level-menu-on-panel-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Here I quotes @user196288 's solution which works for me:

> *Uninstalling Macbuntu will remove appmenu-gtk so you have to install
>    it again:*
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt indicator-appmenu
> ```

Then log out, and log in again, everything comes back.